# how to check internet connection on splash screen

Tags: android

I'm getting the following errors:

1. `ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS` cannot be resolved or is not a field `(build = new Builder(Context); )`
2. Context cannot be resolved to a variable `(build = new Builder(Context); )`
3. Type mismatch: `cannot convert from AnimatorSet.Builder to AlertDialog.Builder(  startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));)`

**SplashScreen.java**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
static ConnectivityManager cm;
AlertDialog dailog;
AlertDialog.Builder build;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
build = new Builder(Context); 

 if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
     .isConnectedOrConnecting()
     || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
             .isConnectedOrConnecting()// if connection is
// there screen goes
// to next screen
// else shows
// message toast
) {
 Log.e("cm value", "" + cm.getAllNetworkInfo().toString());
 Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Internet is active", 2000)
         .show();
 Thread mythread = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
         try {

             sleep(5000);

         } catch (Exception e) {
         } finally {
             Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                     MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
             finish();
         }
     }
 };
 mythread.start();
} else {

 build.setMessage("This application requires Internet connection.Would you connect to            internet ?");
 build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         finish();
         startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));

     }
 });
 build.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         build.setMessage("Are sure you want to exit?");
         build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 finish();
             }
         });
         build.setNegativeButton("NO", new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 finish();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                         SplashScreen.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

                 dialog.dismiss();

             }
         });
         dailog = build.create();
         dailog.show();
     }
 });
 dailog = build.create();
 dailog.show();

}

 }

@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return true;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper class :

```
public class NetworkManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // LOG
    protected static final String   TAG                 = NetworkManager.class.getSimpleName();
    // DATA
    protected Context               mContext;
    protected boolean               mNoConnectivity;
    protected String                mReason;
    protected boolean               mIsFailover;
    protected static boolean        mIsConnected        = false;
    protected static boolean        mIsConnectivityGood = true;

    public NetworkManager(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void registerReceivers() {
        mContext.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context) {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && isConnectionFast(info.getType(), info.getSubtype()));
    }

    protected static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType) {
        if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            switch (subType) {
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                    return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                    return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                    return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                    return false; // ~ 100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                    return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                    return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                    return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                    return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mNoConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        mReason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        mIsFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);
        //
        if (mNoConnectivity) {
            mIsConnected = false;
        }
        else {
            if (isConnectedFast(mContext)) {
                mIsConnectivityGood = true;
            }
            else {
                mIsConnectivityGood = false;
            }
            mIsConnected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can either use the broadcast receiver to get the event in activity either juste use the static method to check connectivity ponctually.

Comment: Delete everything concerning connectivity in your activity the in your if just use NetworkManager.isConnected(this) that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to check if the device has internet..

```
public static boolean hasInternet(Activity a) {
    boolean hasConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean hasConnectedMobile = false;
    try {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) a.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("wifi"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    hasConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("mobile"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    hasConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return hasConnectedWifi || hasConnectedMobile;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        CommonUtils.postException(ex, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i already have this function  please read the description , im getting 3 errors in my code

Comment: What's ur exact requirement? if you just want to check if the device has internet or not and then proceed to start why are making it complicated? if (internet) then go to next activity else finish

Comment: i have two activities, SplashScreen.java is my splashscreen activity and MainActivity.java is my other activity , so when i open my app, it should show splash screen for 3 seconds and if internet is connected, it should simply take me to MainActivity.java and if there is NO internet, it should show a dialog "this application requires internet connection, would you turn on your internet?" along with two buttons "yes" and "exit", if i click on yes, it should show wireless settings and i should be able to turn on internet and when i press back button, i should be taken to MainActivity.

Comment: and if i tap exit, it should exit the app.